# Am I graduate if I take my bachelor degree in Italy?

Tags: education

I don't know if it is appropriate to ask here such a question since it doesn't involve a specific mathematical problem, but I think such information will be useful for many people like me...

My real question is: can I submit paper (i.e. try to write a paper to submit) to an **undergraduate journal**?

I mean journal like

- [The Rose-Hulman Undergraduate Mathematics Journal](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/mathjournal/about.php)
- [SIAM Undergraduate Research Online (SIURO)](http://www.siam.org/students/siuro/)
- [The Harvard College Mathematics Review](http://www.thehcmr.org/)

Here I explain were is the problem...
I'm an italian student with a bachelor degree. 
Here, for mathematics student, we have 3 years of bachelor plus two more year of "specialization" or "magistral graduation". Some years ago, it was one whole iter, but it is now divided in these two parts. 
After these first three years we're used to say to foreign people that we're taking our master (that is the "specialization"), but actually with master in italian we refer only on some really specialized education program of about one year that you can attend after you're three-years-degree (for a "master of first level") or your specialization (for a "master of second level").
Since in Italy you were graduated only after five years of university, but now things are changed, I'm wondering if (despite the new terminology above) I can consider myself still an undergraduate, and then if the above journal are still open for me.

Comment: It will probably vary from journal to journal - write to each journal individually, describe to them your situation and await their response.

Comment: Right; it might be better to ask the journal (editors) rather than us...

Comment: You can  certainly submit a paper to the third journal you list (disclaimer: I'm involved with it), though it's not a research journal; I'm assuming you were planning to write an expository or semi-expository article.

Comment: @AkhilMathew Right. Thank you everybody for your answers.